# Getting plot data from date-range efficiently

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create utilization graph for a telephone system. I have sets of data which is in the table format

```
ID *
StartDate
EndDate
From
To
```

What I'm trying to do is get SQL to to output me a list of plot points every 5 minutes, so basically

The count of active calls (between StartDate and EndDate) for every 5 minutes in a day.

The result beign something like

```
Date Time             Count  
2000-01-01 00:00:00   10
2000-01-01 00:05:00   2
2000-01-01 00:10:00   7
```

Can anyone suggest a way to generate said data? I'm at a loss here! The stuff I've been thinking abut all involves a creating a big loop and running a query for every 5 seconds which seems super inefficient.

---

The method I was originally thinking was :-

```
storedProc GetSamples(SampleStartDate, SampleEndDate)

    Create memory table for result data

    for every 5mins as sample between SampleStartDate and SampleEndDate
        SELECT @SampleCount = COUNT(1) FROM Samples where 5mins BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
        UPDATE memoryTable SET count=@SampleCount WHERE time = 5mins
    end
end
```

Comment: Is this running for a single days' data only, or for multiple days?

Comment: It might be worthwhile showing your attempt to give people a starting point and to demonstrate that you have at least attempted a solution, however bad you think it is :)

Comment: @AHiggins multiple days. But the same premise, I pass in a start date and end date to the function

Comment: @Tanner I've added some pseudocode to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a recent enough version of SQL Server (2008+), you ought to be able to do this with a CTE joined to your phone call log, like this (CTE base found [here](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/t-sql-using-common-table-expressions-cte-to-generate-sequences/)):

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StartDate = '2000-01-01 00:00:00.000'
SET @EndDate = '2000-01-02 00:00:00.000'

;WITH DateSequence( [PlotPointDate] ) AS 
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS [PlotPointDate] 

    UNION ALL 

    SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 5, [PlotPointDate] )
    FROM DateSequence
    WHERE [PlotPointDate]  < @EndDate
)

--select result
SELECT 
    PlotPointDate, COUNT(YourTable.ID) AS TotalActiveCalls
FROM 
    DateSequence 
     LEFT JOIN 
    YourTable ON 
        YourTable.StartDate <= DateSequence.PlotPointDate AND
        (YourTable.EndDate >= DateSequence.PlotPointDate  OR YourTable.EndDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY PlotPointDate
OPTION (MaxRecursion 10000)
```

Comment: Thanks this has helped a tonne, however it runs into a different problem, because we are left joining we are also getting a count = 1 for all records. So even if there isn't a call at a certain time the count always comes back as one.

Comment: @JohnMitchell, thanks for the feedback. That's easy enough to tweak - check the revised code and let me know if it works.